# How to set hashUrl to module's defaultRoute in Yii2 / Angular

Tags: angularjs, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am building a single page web application using **Yii2(basic)** and **Angular 5**. My backend is a module rather than a separate Yii application.

```
$config = [
     ... codes .....
     'modules' => [
         'backend' => [
             'class' => 'app\modules\backend\Module',
             'defaultRoute' => 'admin',
         ],
     ]
];
```

The page navigation is managed from angular side as **#route** ( hashtag route url) like **[root_path]/web/#/user/dashboard** (for frontend) and **[root_path]/web/backend/#/admin/dashboard** (for backend).

So, whenever i navigate to **[root_path]/web/backend**, i want to automatically redirect the url to **[root_path]/web/backend/#/admin/dashboard**. For this, i tried changing the default route of backend module as:

```
    $config = [
     ... codes .....
     'modules' => [
         'backend' => [
             'class' => 'app\modules\backend\Module',
             'defaultRoute' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/admin','#' => '/admin/dashboard']),
         ],
     ]
];
```

AND

```
    $config = [
     ... codes .....
     'modules' => [
         'backend' => [
             'class' => 'app\modules\backend\Module',
             'defaultRoute' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/backend/admin/index','#' => '/admin/dashboard']),
         ],
     ]
];
```

But I got this error : 
[image]

Can anyone point me out what I am doing wrong? 
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Url::to()` on defining configuration. At this point application is not yet initialized, so `UrlManager` component (which is used by `Url` helper) does not exist. So you're creating chicken-egg problem - you need Application to initialize Application.

And even if you could use it, there is no much sense in what you're trying to do. `defaultRoute` is not the same as URL and it has nothing to do with redirections - assigning URL into it will not bring anything good. 
Moreover, part of URL after `#` is not sent to the server, so you never get request for URL `/web/backend/#/admin/dashboard`. From Yii perspective there is no difference whether user is on `/web/backend/#/admin/dashboard` or `/web/backend/` - it will always be seen as `/web/backend/`.

If you want such redirection, you should handle it in JavaScript and perform at browser level.